# Making Azure blob Url accessible only to Logged in users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have an application and user can see images stored on azure blob storage. I want image urls to only works if a user is logged in. Copying image url and pasting on another browser should not work. Not sure how this can be done. Already using SAS with an expiry time on it. So link would work for half an hour. I want to make it accessible for logged in user only instead of time bounding it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an alternative approach - expose your image retrieval functionality as it's own controller (Image controller). This will allow you to restrict access to images only to logged in users. Remove the public access from your container if you do that.

Another benefit to this approach is that if you chose to host your images elsewhere (i.e. not in blob storage), you will only need to change your controller, and other parts of your code will remain unchanged. That is, the controller encapsulates your image hosting logic.

Comment: How this would work? <img> tag needs an actual url to display image. How would translate that to something else?

Comment: In your tags, you wrote asp.net, so I assume you have some rest endpoint which your application is communicating with. In that case, the get endpoint of your controller will now serve as the url: www.yoursitename.com/Images/imageid.

Comment: Some more details - the get image endpoint will return an HttpResponseMessage with the picture bytes as content and ontent.Headers.ContentType be your image type, e.g. MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg")

Answer (score 1):

I usually use HttpHandler.

Sample snippet:

```
    public class BlobHandler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
    {    
     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
     {
        var request = context.Request;
        var response = context.Response;
        var path = request.Url.AbsolutePath;
        var parts = path.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        // fetch record from db
       var attachment = Attachment.FetchByUrl(parts[parts.length - 1]);

       if (attachment == null)
            throw new HttpException(404, "Blob not found.");

        // helper method - get a blob instance, if it doesn't exist return null
        var blob = CloudStorage.GetBlob(Constants.StoragePrivateContainer, attachment.BlobPath);

        if (blob == null)
            throw new HttpException(404, "Blob not found.");

        // custom auth
        if (!context.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            throw new HttpException(403, "Access denied.");

        var p = context.User as CustomPrincipal;

        if (p == null)
            throw new HttpException(403, "Access denied.");

        if (!p.IsInRole(Enums.Role.Downloader))
            throw new HttpException(403, "Access denied.");

        blob.DownloadToStream(context.Response.OutputStream);
            response.ContentType = blob.Properties.ContentType;
            response.Flush();            
    }

    public bool IsReusable => true;
   }
```

Ignore "blob" path in RouteConfig:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("blob/{*pathInfo}");
```

Add handler into handlers section in web.config:

```
<add name="Blobs" path="blob/*" verb="*" type="MyLibrary.BlobHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

As others suggested - do not forget to set your Container as "private".

Comment: Isn't memory extensive as we are downloading blob first? not directly setting <img src=[blob url]>

Comment: When making for example html images you just use: <img src="/blob/blabla.jpg" />

Comment: Getting instance of CloudBlockBlob doesn't load content of the blob (even getting metadata you need to call FetchAttributes method for example). In HTTP handler you just open HTTP response stream and "fill" it with bytes directly from blob content.

Comment: My image Urls are held in a database table I am querying it with EF. not sure where this handler would come into play

Comment: You make query in the handler itself.

Comment: I updated my snippet. You need to understand this handler is triggered by HTTP request. In my case path /blob/anything.ext will end up in ProcessRequest request method of that handler. After that you can do whatever you want... fetch record from db, check rights, ... modify headers, return any HTTP code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129375/discussion-between-intheworldofcodingapplications-and-j-f).

Comment: my repository return IQuerable of var containerSas = GetSas();
       var serverUrl= "https://myblobAccount.blob.core.windows.net/"
       var result = from ar in this._context.articles
                        select new Observation()
                        {
                            Id = ar.Id,
                            Title = ar.Title,
                            Images = (from img in this._context.Images
                                      select serverUrl + img.ImageFileName + containerSas).ToList()
                        };  How this be moved to Hanlder

Answer (score 0):

To access documents in Blob Storage, they can be either

1. Public
2. Accessed with key
3. Accessed with a SAS token

Storage cannot know about your authentication system. If you do not wish to bind the token by time, you can set up a shared access policy in the container, set the expiry time there, and just refer to the policy in the SAS token. Then you can set the expiry time again later on the policy without regenerating the token.

But otherwise time-bound SAS tokens are the only thing you can do.

Comment: But you could still access the URL if before the SAS token expires.